# Backbone complex sort issues

Tags: sorting, backbone.js

I want to sort a collection by two attributes, one is "complete", which returns true or false, and the second is by id, except I need that one to be in descending. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that sort of thing. A collection's [`comparator`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator) takes a one argument or two argument function:

> Comparator function can be defined as either a [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) (pass a function that takes a single argument), or as a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments).

You would want to use the two-argument form, something like this:

```
comparator: function(a, b) {
    var ac = a.get('complete');
    var bc = b.get('complete');
    if(ac && !bc)
        return 1;
    if(!ac && bc)
        return -1;

    var as = a.get('seconds');
    var bs = b.get('seconds');
    if(as > bs)
        return -1;
    if(bs < as)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

If you have an older version of Backbone that doesn't understand the two-argument `comparator` function then you'll have to upgrade or figure out a way to mash `complete` and `seconds` together into a single sort key that will sort properly with [Underscore's `sortBy`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy).

Comment: Nice. This example was immensely helpful. Thanks again Mu.